# DynamicComponent not refresshing when changing the component type

Tags: blazor, render, blazor-webassembly, dynamic-components

``<DynamicComponent Type="SelectedQuestionTemplate" Parameters="parameters" @ref="dynamicComponentRef"/>`

Am in a situation where I need to render the component based on the type selected.

this is how am setting :-

```
SelectedQuestionTemplate = Type.GetType($"CheetahExam.WebUI.Client.Pages.Exam.Questions.Templates.CheckBoxTemplate2");
```

```
**Parameters** = 
 parameters["ExamId"] = ExamId;
 parameters["QuestionId"] = SelectedQuestionId;
 parameters["OnDelete"] = EventCallback.Factory.Create<bool>(
                                         this, HandleQuestionDelete);
 parameters["OnSave"] = EventCallback.Factory.Create<bool>(
                                         this, HandleQuestionSave);

 if (SelectedQuestionType == (int)QuestionTypes.CheckBox)
 {
     SelectedQuestionTemplate = Type.GetType($"CheetahExam.WebUI.Client.Pages.Exam.Questions.Templates.CheckBoxTemplate2");
 }
```

when **SelectedQuestionTemplate** get changes it do not refresh the dynamic component, My tech stack is blazor webassebly , .net 7 with C# 11,

I followed the below code from (**https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/dynamiccomponent?view=aspnetcore-7.0**)

```
<DynamicComponent Type="typeof({COMPONENT})" @ref="dc" />

<button @onclick="Refresh">Refresh</button>

@code {
    private DynamicComponent? dc;

    private Task Refresh()
    {
        return (dc?.Instance as IRefreshable)?.Refresh();
    }
}
```

I wanted to achive to dynamically render the componenet based on the selected type and parameters

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/dynamiccomponent?view=aspnetcore-7.0`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/dynamiccomponent?view=aspnetcore-7.0%60)

Answer (score 0):

I think your primary problem is in this line

```cs
<DynamicComponent Type="typeof({COMPONENT})" @ref="dc" />
```

`{COMPONENT}` means the real component.

Here's a even simpler working example you can paste into *Home* in the standard template:

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary mb-3" @onclick="this.OnClick">Switch</button>
</div>

<DynamicComponent Type="_activeComponent" Parameters="_parameters" />

@code{
    private Type _activeComponent = typeof(Counter);
    private Dictionary<string, object> _parameters = new();

    private Task OnClick()
    {
        if (_activeComponent == typeof(Counter))
        {
            _activeComponent = typeof(Weather);
            _parameters = new();
        }
        else
        {
            _activeComponent = typeof(Counter);
            _parameters = new();
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```